# What is the best way to call template.ParseFiles() dynamically in Go instead of passing in x number of strings?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I want to load a folder of HTML templates in Go and right now I can only pass in each file path as a string in an argument.

Example:

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("../web/html_templates/edit.html", "../web/html_templates/view.html"))
```

Works fine.

This and similar solutions won't work:

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("../web/html_templates/*"))
```

I'd like to specify my templates in a config file but I currently can't. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You could have your program list all the HTML files in that directory, and pass the resulting list to `ParseFiles`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ParseGlob](http://godoc.org/html/template#ParseGlob) to parse a folder of HTML templates in one API call.

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("../web/html_templates/*.html"))
```

See the [Match](http://godoc.org/path/filepath#Match) function documentation for the glob syntax.

Comment: In addition to using `ParseGlob` you can also build a map or slice of templates using `filepath.Walk` if your requirements don't fit globbing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the fact that [template.ParseFiles](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) is a [variadic function](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions) :

```
var templatesFiles []string
// [...]
// Here fill the slice from your config file or any other source
// [...]
templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(templatesFiles...))
```